# Mediatek flash tool device in device manager disconnects

Tags: rom, flashtool

I am trying to flash a rom via mediatek flash tool, my problem is that when I connect the tablet to my PC it connects the mediatek preloader but after 2 seconds it disconnects. What can I do with this ?

Comment: The preloader​ port only lasts 3 seconds then closes, you have to click on the flash button first then connect the device to the computer

Answer (score 0):

### Flash Stock Roms with SP Flash Tool

**Step 1**: 
[Download](https://androiddatahost.com/b9cyw) and install Android USB Drivers on your PC. Skip this step, In case the drivers are already installed.

**Step 2**: **Power Off** your MTK Device.

**Step 3** Download the suitable Firmware for your device, and extract it on your PC.

**Step 4**: [Download](http://spflashtool.com/) and Extract SP Flash Tool on Your PC.

**Step 5**: In the extracted folder, launch **Flash_tool.exe**

**Step 6**: Click on the **Download** Tab.

**Step 7**: In the Download Tab, now click on the **Scatter-Loading** button.

**Step 8**: Navigate in your Firmware Folder and select **Scatter File** (A txt file ending with scatter.txt).

**Step 9**: Click on the **Download** Button to launch the download procedure.

**Step 10**: Connect your device to the PC using the USB Cable. Your device should be Powered-off.

**Step 11**: Once Flashing is completed, a **Green circle** dialog appears, now you can disconnect your device from the USB Cable and Power it on to check whether it's ok or not.

**P.S**: Don't select **Preloader** while flashing unknown Firmwares.

Comment: Thank you, now I have all to flash the tablet, but the only problem I have is that the scatter file in the .zip is in a invalid format (SPFT error). @Abdelhafid Madoui

Comment: Now I flashed the firmware(I found it) and I got download OK, but the tablet is not booting, nothing changed.